# How do I configure an Elastic Agent managed by Fleet to ignore the logging of certain pods?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack

I have deployed Elastic Agents managed by fleet on our Openshift cluster using the following guide:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/running-on-kubernetes-managed-by-fleet.html

We have also successfully configured the integrations within the Fleet agent policies using the UI. All of this worked and we do see the logging of our pods in Kibana. However, there is a lot of unwanted data and we wish to exclude the logging from certain pods to be sent to Elastic.

How can this be done with Agents managed by fleet?

I tried adding the following configuration to "Custom configurations" in the Fleet integration.

```yaml
filebeat.autodiscover:
 providers:
   - type: kubernetes
     hints.enabled: true
     hints.default_config.enabled: false
```

Then I annotated my pods with `co.elastic.logs/enabled: false` as is written [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html). This did not work and to my understanding will not work with non-Standalone agents. Is there an alternative for this that works with Fleet managed agents so that we can exclude certain pods?

Comment: You need to use [conditions based autodiscovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/conditions-based-autodiscover.html?), which in contrast to hints also works with Elastic agents managed by Fleet.

There are [many different properties](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/kubernetes-provider.html) you can use to identify the pods you don't want to log, such as pod names, labels, annotations, etc.

Comment: Looks good but how do I get this to work with Fleet managed agents? In the first link they say to edit the Standalone manifest that includes a agent.yaml, there is no agent.yaml in the Managed manifest. Both can be found here https://github.com/elastic/elastic-agent/tree/main/deploy/kubernetes. It feels to me that the Fleet managed Agents are not open to modification or am I missing something?